# Stage for Indigo allows more than one laser?

Tags: ros, laser, ros-indigo, stage-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I remember that package ros_stage in fuerte/electric didn't allowed it. I found a thread where they made a patch (http://lists.ros.org/message/20101203.131043.e45a3945.en.html, formerly http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Simulating-multiple-laser-scanners-in-Stage-td2008197.html) and used their code. However, has it been solved in indigo version?

---

> I'm trying to make an accurate
> simulation of my robot in stage, but
> I've run into a problem with adding
> multiple laser scanners. I added two
> lasers to the position model in my
> world file, but stage dies on launch
> with the following message:
>
> [FATAL] [1291323094.990198245]: number
> of position models and laser models
> must be equal in the world file.
>
> My robot has one laser on the front,
> and one on the back, both with 180
> degree FOV.
>
> Any help with this would be much
> appreciated.
>
> -Zac

---

> Hi Zac!
>
> The current version of stageros allows
> exactly 1 laser per robot, no more no
> less.
>
> I submitted a ticket with a patch a
> while ago to add the new
> sensor_msgs/Range to stage, and I
> changed it to allow multiple sensors
> per robot.
>
> I you'd like I can send you the
> patched version of stage for your to
> run your sims. I never tried it with 2
> lasers though, just with a laser and a
> sonar on a robot.
>
> Gonçalo Cabrita ISR - University of
> Coimbra Portugal

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196403/stage-for-indigo-allows-more-than-one-laser?/) by [Manuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1917/manuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a pull request to add multisensor support: https://github.com/ros-simulation/stage_ros/pull/10

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0